# What does "never trust your tongue when your heart is bitter" quote mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does the following quote mean?

> Never trust your tongue when your heart is bitter.

Comment: Literary interpretation is off topic. Is there a particular word or grammatical element in the quote which you are trying to ask about?

Comment: A modern paraphrase might be: _Never click SEND until you first calm down._

Comment: It’s somewhat similar to the Irish saying _’Tis often a man’s mouth broke his nose_.

Answer (score 12):

It means when you are angry/upset/sad/etc. that you should be careful that you don't hurt others with your words. It is much more difficult to watch what you say when you are not doing well emotionally.

Comment: It's also a nice play on sensation and body parts. The tongue is the organ that senses **real** bitterness.